# How to find failed jobs list in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using `sidekiq` in `rails4`.
How can I find failed jobs list and reprocesses them to perform in `sidekiq`?

Comment: I think this is what you want https://github.com/mhfs/sidekiq-failures

Answer (score 12):

Try sidekiq-failures , I believe that is what you want.

https://github.com/mhfs/sidekiq-failures

Answer (score 10):

See Sidekiq::RetrySet in `sidekiq/api`

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#retries

Comment: I am getting an error message for ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address. always . Most of the jobs are running but somtimes the jobs get failed due to SMTP. Can you please identify the issue?

Comment: Irrespective of whether a job has been retried or not, we would like to know the failed jobs argument.
I mean if on retry the job has succeeded the retry job will get cleared. However it will still remain in the failed job counter.
So I dont think this is the way.